What model can I use to get a dynamic path from one point to another as an output?
I am working on a drone and want to make it autonomous. As a first step, I decided to make a PyTorch algorithm that can output a path from one point to another. To do that, two random points are generated in a given static adjacency list. Then, using BFS, based on a graph, the optimal path is found. That path is considered y, which is the output the model is supposed to get. The problem is I have no idea what this model should look like.
Elaboration:
This is the algorithm for finding the optimal path: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-path-unweighted-graph/
I have attached a few rows of data with input(X), output(y), and edge list: Rows of data
Also, I have attached a visualization of the graph. Graph is static but I also want to have a dynamic graph structure in the future: Graph structure
Here is my code for data generation:
import random
import pandas as pd
import torch
import torch_geometric.utils as tg
from collections import deque

# Data stages (Start and end points are always random):
    # 1) Static, same structure
    # 2) Semi-dynamic, structure is dynamic but it is derived from 10x10 grid
    # 3) Fully dynamic, structure is dynamic and is not limited in size

# Algorithm for finding the optimal path
def bfs(adjacency_matrix, S, par, dist):
  # Preparing graph by converting long tesnor into int list 
  graph = adjacency_matrix

  # Queue to store the nodes in the order they are visited
  q = deque()
  # Mark the distance of the source node as 0
  dist[S] = 0
  # Push the source node to the queue
  q.append(S)

  # Iterate until the queue is not empty
  while q:
      # Pop the node at the front of the queue
      node = q.popleft()

      # Explore all the neighbors of the current node
      for neighbor in graph[node]:
          # Check if the neighboring node is not visited
          if dist[neighbor] == float('inf'):
              # Mark the current node as the parent of the neighboring node
              par[neighbor] = node
              # Mark the distance of the neighboring node as the distance of the current node + 1
              dist[neighbor] = dist[node] + 1
              # Insert the neighboring node to the queue
              q.append(neighbor)
    
  return dist


def get_shortest_distance(adjacency_matrix, S, D, V):
  # par[] array stores the parent of nodes
  par = [-1] * V

  # dist[] array stores the distance of nodes from S
  dist = [float('inf')] * V

  # Function call to find the distance of all nodes and their parent nodes
  dist = bfs(adjacency_matrix, S, par, dist)

  if dist[D] == float('inf'):
      print("Source and Destination are not connected")
      return

  # List path stores the shortest path
  path = []
  current_node = D
  path.append(D)
  while par[current_node] != -1:
      path.append(par[current_node])
      current_node = par[current_node]

  # Printing path from source to destination
  return path


# Global parameters
# n = random.randint(0,100)
num_nodes = 11



def generate_dataset(n, num_nodes):
    dataset = []
    for _ in range(n):
        # Generating random source and destination nodes ---------------------
        source = random.randint(0, num_nodes-1)
        destination = random.randint(0, num_nodes-1)
        
        # Find optimal path --------------------------------------------------
        # TODO: edge_index must be dynamically initialized in the stages 2 and 3
        edge_index = [[0, 1, 0, 7, 1, 4, 7, 4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 4, 5, 5, 10, 2, 3, 3, 6, 6, 2, 8, 10, 6, 10, 9, 3],
                      [1, 0, 7, 0, 4, 1, 4, 7, 2, 1, 5, 4, 8, 7, 5, 4, 10, 5, 3, 2, 6, 3, 2, 6, 10, 8, 10, 6, 3, 9]]

        # List to store the graph as an adjacency list
        graph = [[] for _ in range(num_nodes)]

        for i, node in enumerate(edge_index[0]):
            graph[node].append(edge_index[1][i])

        path = get_shortest_distance(graph, source, destination, num_nodes)

        # TODO 3: Initialize Y
        
        # Generating X, and Y ----------------------------------------------------
        # X = nx1 size list of values of each node
        X = [[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
        X[source] = [-1]
        X[destination] = [2]

        # Y = nodes to go to to reach destination. Minimum size: 1
        # path is reversed to follow s->d route
        Y = path[::-1]
        
        dataset.append([edge_index, X, Y])
    return dataset

# Generate a dataset
dataset = generate_dataset(10000, num_nodes)

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(dataset, columns=["Edge index", "X", "Y"])

# Write the DataFrame to an CSV file
df.to_csv("./data/raw/data.csv", index=False)

The question is: how can I use GCN(and maybe some other kinds of layers) to get a dynamic output(sometimes the path is very short, so its just 1 or 2 numbers that represent which nodes to go to and sometimes the path is long)?
I am just looking for a direction. What layers should I use, what approach should I consider?
Preferably, this approach needs to work with dynamic topologies(each row of data = differently structured graph) as well.
Please, feel free to take a look at my current code if that helps, but only the data generation code and visualization are implemented: https://github.com/netiRussell/pythonNotes/tree/main/Projects/FindShortPathGCN
I have tried using the classification approach with nn.CrossEntropyLoss(); however, it requires an output that is the same size as the input in terms of number of nodes. This doesn't work as I am not going to have each node represent a step, I just need the steps themselves as an output.

A full answer is well outside the scope of a stackoverflow answer, but you could consider treating it a node classification problem. Input is the graph with start/end nodes defined. The model classifies each node as 1 (on path) or 0 (off path). You could also treat it as a sequence generation problem. Have a GCN encoder -> transformer/LSTM decoder that outputs a variable length sequence of node ID values

@Karl , Could you elaborate on the second approach? Is there downsides to it in terms of precision?

You would represent the shortest path as a list of node ids - ie [0, 12, 8, ...]. The transformer decoder would autoregressively predict the node id sequence. One limit is you would have to set a maximum supported node count

@ Karl, Thank you, I will look into that

@Karl, I'm currently studying Transformers and was curious if you know any good examples of Transformers NN being used with graphs( as far as I understand, it's mostly used for text generation)? Preferably with PyTorch. I appreciate your help!
